# mounted samba share saving files to local disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, samba, fstab, disk-usage

My Ubuntu computer is reporting that the local disk is full. The computer is primarily used for homeassistant and frigate and I have a Windows file server mounted to Ubuntu to save security camera recordings. I followed the advice in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate) and mounted my filesystem to a temporary mount location. Running du showed that my mount for the cameras is indeed saving to local disk. I deleted all recordings off of the widows file system and they still show up in du like this:

```
435G    /mnt/test/mnt
435G    /mnt/test/mnt/cameras
435G    /mnt/test/mnt/cameras/recordings
435G    /mnt/test/mnt/cameras/recordings/2023-04
453G    /mnt/test
```

I am at a loss as to why this is happening and how to fix it. I am a bit of a linux noob so I am not sure if I mounted the share incorrectly or if it is an issue with frigate. Here is what my mount looks like in fstab:

```
//192.168.1.99/Cameras /mnt/cameras cifs credentials=/home/everett/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Also here is the section of my docker compose file for firgate where the mount is assigned to frigates recording folder:

```
 frigate:
container_name: frigate
privileged: true # this may not be necessary for all setups
restart: unless-stopped
image: blakeblackshear/frigate:stable
shm_size: "600mb" # update for your cameras based on calculation above
devices:
  - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb # passes the USB Coral, needs to be modified for other versions
  - /dev/dri/card0 # for intel hwaccel, needs to be updated for your hardware
volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - /opt/frigate/config/config.yaml:/config/config.yml:ro
  - /mnt/cameras:/media/frigate
  - /opt/frigate/db:/db
  - type: tmpfs # Optional: 1GB of memory, reduces SSD/SD Card wear
    target: /tmp/cache
    tmpfs:
      size: 1000000000
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
  - "1935:1935" # RTMP feeds
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your fstab entry looks like it’s trying to mount your server at /mnt/Cameras (Cameras with a capital C). Your docker file wants to use /mnt/cameras. So that’s not the same location. The files on your system are below /mnt/test….   That’s another location. Correct the mount points in fstab and docker. Then If your server is mounted successfully and you want to keep the data below /mnt/test you can move it to the server to release space. After that any new data should be in the right place